# call function on using codemirror edit

Tags: javascript, function, callback, pretty-print, codemirror

i am currently experimenting a markdown text editor, i found on:
[uikit markdown editor](http://getuikit.com/docs/addons_markdownarea.html)

but i could not found a way to get a callback when inserting or editing.

is there anyway to call a function whenever user editing or pasting something?

I am trying to call `prettyprint()` whenever user edit something and the prettyprint will execute make code on the preview side prettyprinted.

right now i am using interval to execute the prettyprint and it works but i want more precise way to call it.

Comment: hello! is there anyone can help me??

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Marijn suggested,
I would like to give a sample code for the reference:

```
        editor.on("change",function(cm,obj){
               alert("Content Changed");
               console.log(obj);
    });
```

where 'editor' is the CodeMirror instance.

Comment: Nice :) was looking for this

Answer (score 0):

CodeMirror raises a `"change"` event whenever the document is modified. See http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#event_change